# Why following c code not work in the initialization section of for-loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a=10;
    int b =9;
    
    for((a>b)?printf("a>b"):printf("a<b");i<3;i++)
    {
       printf("inside for loop");
    }

}
```

this line compiles fine:

```
for((a>b)?printf("a>b"):printf("a<b");i<3;i++)
```

but

```
for(if(a>b){pritnf("a>b");};i<3;i++)
```

and if use for-loop OR while-loop in the initialization section give error

Is there any rule about initialization section in for-loop that i'm not aware of ??

Comment: What is the error message? `pritnf` is clearly a typo, which may account for the error, but I don't think that's the only problem.

Comment: The for-loop header can only contain expressions and variable initializations, not other statements.

Comment: Why are you putting a `printf()` in the variable initialization section of the `for` loop?

Comment: What's the purpose of this monstrosity? Are you just exploring what's possible or trying to write good code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this since the code clearly does not compile and does not include error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Look at some [for loop documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for):

> init-clause may be an expression or a declaration (since C99).

An `if` statement is neither an expression nor a declaration. It is a statement. Hence, it may not be used as an init-clause for a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

A [`for` loop is a **statement** defined as](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5):

```
      iteration-statement:
              while ( expression ) statement
              do statement while ( expression ) ;
              for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
              for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

And [an `if` is a **statement** defined as](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4):

```
      selection-statement:
              if ( expression ) statement
              if ( expression ) statement else statement
              switch ( expression ) statement
```

Note that a `for` loop requires **expressions**, and that an `if` is  a **statement**.

Statements are not [expressions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5), so `for ( if (...)... ; ... ; ... )` is illegal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the variable i;